# Can I make tooltips stay on click in plotly-dash?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm trying to make a tooltip that appears when marker is hovered, to stay when the marker is clicked. Or, maybe, some other kind of text annotation to appear and stay on click.
I’m working with markers on a map, if that helps.
Thanks

Comment: There's no way to do this at the moment, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Dash Leaflet. Here is a small example,

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_leaflet as dl

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dl.Map(children=[dl.TileLayer(), dl.Marker(position=(56, 10), children=dl.Popup("I am a popup"))],
           style={'width': "100%", 'height': "100%"}, center=[56, 10], zoom=8),
], style={'width': '1000px', 'height': '500px'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of Dash Leaflet.

Comment: Thanks for making dash leaflet, looking forward to trying it out, Folium in iframes just doesn't cut it.